# R - corrplot correlation matrix division

Tags: r, r-corrplot

Here I make an example 12x12 correlation matrix:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(20),x2=rnorm(20),x3=rnorm(20),x4=rnorm(20),x5=rnorm(20),x6=rnorm(20),x7=rnorm(20),x8=rnorm(20),x9=rnorm(20),x10=rnorm(20),x11=rnorm(20),x12=rnorm(20))
cormatx <- cor(df)
corrplot(cormatx, method="color")
```

I was wondering how this one output could be divided in to four separate 6x6 matrixes? Here is an image of how the output should be divided. I hope this makes sense.
[image]

Comment: Do you just want the lines added?

Comment: Nope. I want the script to vomit out four separate 6x6 matrixes instead of one larger 12x12 matrix.

Comment: Have you looked at `image`?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think I need to divide `cormatx` to those bits. The image is just there to simplify the needed output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
corrplot(cormatx[1:6,1:6], method="color")  
corrplot(cormatx[1:6,7:12], method="color")  
corrplot(cormatx[7:12,1:6], method="color")  
corrplot(cormatx[7:12,7:12], method="color")
```