# Correlation plot with double legends

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

So I want to build a correlation plot for an N*N matrix. But, the difference is that I want the `upper-triangular` and the `lower-triangular` to have different colors. Because the `upper-triangular` matrix will represent `Z-squared` values and the `lower-triangular`, `D prime`. Of course, the diagonal should be white to denote the equalities.

How can this be done with R? I checked `corrplot` and other alternatives in Google but I can't figure it out. Can this be done?

An example matrix for `Z-scores` could be a matrix like so:

```
    SNP1 SNP2 SNP3 SNP4 ... 
SNP1 1 0.0007 0.05 0.004 ...
SNP2 0.003 1 0.00001 0.02 0.000003 ...
```

Same applies to `D-prime` matrixes. I just want to plot them with different colors in the **same** correlation matrix.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the anwer to your question but maybe you will find something useful in `corrplot.mixed()` documentation?

Comment: You say that the upper and lower triangles will represent different values. What values? From two different correlation matrices? Please be more explicit about what you want to plot.  In addition,  providing some sample data with the desired outcome would be the best.  Please see [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @kaksat thank you for your quick response. the problem is the double legend that i'm after because the 2 values that I want to plot are. `corrplot` does not offer that.

Comment: @G5W I've updated the question. please check it again.

Comment: you can define the upper and lower separately, example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352503/change-text-color-in-corrplot-mixed

Comment: @user20650 I will look in to that! thanks!