# R: corrplot.mixed: how do I keep the column names and row names displayed, and how do I make the diagonal have a different color than the rest

Tags: r, r-corrplot

If I make a regular correlation plot in R like this, it displays the column and row names normally:

```
dat <- matrix(scan(),3,byrow=TRUE)
.06 .36 .07 
.10 .03 -.34
.20 .4  -.20

colnames(dat) <- c("a","b","c")
rownames(dat) <- c("a","b","c")

corrplot(dat, method="circle")
```

[image]

However, if I make a mixed plot, with the upper half containing circles and the lower half + diagonal as numbers, the labels disappear:

```
corrplot.mixed(dat, lower="number", upper="circle",diag = "l")
```

[image]

My main question is: how do I keep the column labels and row labels displayed in the same place as in the first plot?

My second question regarding this example: is it possible to display the diagonal as numbers that are not colored according to the correlations and have them appear, for example, all in black.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add the argument `tl.pos ="lt"` to your call to `corrplot.mixed`. This makes the labels appear on top and on the left. Other options are `d` for diagonal and `n` for none.

so, your code becomes:

```
corrplot.mixed(dat, lower="number", upper="circle", diag = "l", tl.pos = "lt")
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! Any ideas on the second question? (how to make the numbers on the diagonal all black)

Comment: I am looking for a solution. Is it an option to use `corrplot` in stead of `corrplot.mixed`? I found something [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352503/change-text-color-in-corrplot-mixed).